# Kafka error: Erroneous state

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

Задача состоит в том, чтобы подписаться на топик в кафке и считать данные со смещением по указанной дате.
При попытке вызвать метод `Seek()` получаю ошибку:

> Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException: Local: Erroneous state

Вот мой код:

```
adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(_kafkaConfig.AsEnumerable()).Build();
var topicMetadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(_config.Topic, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var partitions = topicMetadata
    .Topics
    .First(x => x.Topic == _config.Topic)
    .Partitions;
var partitionsOffsets = partitions
    .Select(x => new TopicPartitionTimestamp(_config.Topic, x.PartitionId, new Timestamp(_config.OffsetDateUtc)));

consumer = CreateConsumer();

foreach (var p in partitions)
{
    consumer.Assign(new TopicPartition(_config.Topic, p.PartitionId));
}

var offsets = consumer.OffsetsForTimes(partitionsOffsets, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

//await Task.Delay(1000);

foreach (var o in offsets)
{
    consumer.Seek(o);
}
```

Но если я добавляю ожидание: `await Task.Delay(1000);` то ошибка не появляется. Как мне правильно задать смещение, чтобы ошибка не появлялась без ожидания?

Comment: А можно уточнить в вопросе, в какое место кода Вы добавляете ожидание?

Comment: @S.H. В примере кода есть закомментированная строка, она стоит перед тем, как я вызываю метод `Seek()`

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. я посмотрел на код - очень странно, что в этом месте задержка на что то влияет. Код выглядит как обычный синхроный код. К сожалению, не знаю, в чем проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл верный ответ на вопрос:

```cs
var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(_kafkaConfig.AsEnumerable()).Build();
var topicMetadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(_config.Topic, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var partitions = topicMetadata
    .Topics
    .First(x => x.Topic == _config.Topic)
    .Partitions;
var partitionsOffsets = partitions
    .Select(x => new TopicPartitionTimestamp(_config.Topic, x.PartitionId, new Timestamp(_config.OffsetDateUtc)));

consumer = CreateConsumer();

var offsets = consumer.OffsetsForTimes(partitionsOffsets, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

foreach (var o in offsets)
{
    consumer.Assign(o); 
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что сначала шла подписка на `Partitions`, а потом поиск по топику `consumer.Seek()`

```cs
foreach (var p in partitions)
{
    consumer.Assign(new TopicPartition(_config.Topic, p.PartitionId));
}

foreach (var o in offsets)
{
    consumer.Seek(o); 
}
```

Следующая строка задаёт создаёт необходимые параметры для прдписки на нужные `Partitions` с нужным смещением:

```cs
var offsets = consumer.OffsetsForTimes(partitionsOffsets, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]